# selecting a specific value from a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select a value from a dataframe. But the problem is the output is with data type and column name. 
Here is my data frame which i am reading from a csv file,

```
Name,Code
blackberry,1
wineberry,2
rasberry,1
blueberry,1
mulberry,2
```

And here is my testing code-

```
dataFrame=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
value = dataFrame.loc[dataFrame['Name'] == 'rasberry']['Code']
print(value)
strvalue=str(value)
if(strvalue=="1"):
    print("got it")
```

The expected ouput of `value` would be `1` but it is

```
2  1\nName: Code, dtype: int64
```

and that's why the if condition is not working. How can I get the specific value?
I am using `pandas`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *value* you get is a Series object. You can use `.iloc` to extract the value from it:

```
value.iloc[0]
# 1
```

Or you can use `.values` to extract the underlying numpy array and then use index to extract the value:

```
value.values[0]
# 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## Break It Down

1. `dataFrame['Name']` returns a `pd.Series`
2. `dataFrame['Name'] == 'rasberry'` returns a `pd.Series` with `dtype` `bool`
3. `dataFrame.loc[dataFrame['Name'] == 'rasberry']` uses the boolean `pd.Series` to slice `dataFrame` returning a `pd.DataFrame` that is a subset of `dataFrame`
4. `dataFrame.loc[dataFrame['Name'] == 'rasberry']['code']` is a `pd.Series` that is the column named `'code'` in the sliced dataframe from step 3.

   - If you expect the elements in the `'Name'` column to be unique, then this will be a one row `pd.Series`.
   - You want the element inside but at this point it's the difference between `'value'` and `['value']`

---

## Setup

```
from io import StringIO

txt = """Name,Code
blackberry,1
wineberry,2
rasberry,1
blueberry,1
mulberry,2"""
```

## Solution(s)

### use `iloc` to grab first value

```
dataFrame=pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt))
value = dataFrame.query('Name == "rasberry"').Code.iloc[0]
print(value)
```

### use `iat` to grab first value

```
dataFrame=pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt))
value = dataFrame.query('Name == "rasberry"').Code.iat[0]
print(value)
```

### specify index column when reading in csv and use `loc`

```
dataFrame=pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), index_col='Name')
value = dataFrame.loc['rasberry', 'Code']
print(value)
```

### specify index column when reading in csv and use `at`

```
dataFrame=pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), index_col='Name')
value = dataFrame.at['rasberry', 'Code']
print(value)
```

### specify index column when reading in csv and use `get_value`

```
dataFrame=pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), index_col='Name')
value = dataFrame.get_value('rasberry', 'Code')
print(value)
```

### specify the index column when reading the csv and `squeeze` into a series if only one non index column exists

```
series=pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), index_col='Name', squeeze=True)
value = series.rasberry
print(value)
```