# pandas returning line number and type?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a csv file, and using python get the highest average price of avocado from the data. All works fine until printing the region

```
avocadoesDB = pd.read_csv("avocado.csv")
avocadoesDB = pd.DataFrame(avocadoesDB)
avocadoesDB = avocadoesDB[['AveragePrice', 'type', 'year', 'region']]



regions = avocadoesDB[['AveragePrice', 'region']]
regionMax = max(regions['AveragePrice'])
region = regions.loc[regions['AveragePrice']==regionMax]


print(f"The highest average price for both types of potatoes is ${regionMax} from {region['region']}.")
```

Output:

```
The highest average price for both types of potatoes is $3.25 from 14125    SanFrancisco
Name: region, dtype: object.
```

Expected:

```
The highest average price for both types of potatoes is $3.25 from SanFrancisco.
```

Comment: I must add, I imported pandas as pd, and forgot to add it in the code snippet above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've tried to copy the similar method on a simple dataset and i've seem to make it work, here's the code snippet

```
mx = max(df1['Salary'])
plc = df.loc[df1['Salary']==mx]['Name']
print('Max Sal : ' + str(plc.iloc[0]))
```

Output:

```
Max Sal : Farah
```

According to [this post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41925378/selecting-a-specific-value-from-a-data-frame), when you use `df.loc[df1['Salary']==mx]['Name']` , A Series Object is returned, and so to retrieve the value of the desired column, you use `[0]`, if I understood the post correctly.

So for your code, you can replace

```
region = regions.loc[regions['AveragePrice']==regionMax]
print(f"The highest average price for both types of potatoes is ${regionMax} from {region['region']}.")
```

with

```
region = regions.loc[regions['AveragePrice']==regionMax]['region']

print(f"The highest average price for both types of potatoes is ${regionMax} from {region}.")
```

This should work. Hope this helps!